# Using FlatList to display custom card elements and need to make them touchable

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I need to make the list of items touchable in a flatlist, but have no idea how to make the individual components touchable so i can access the id of that flatlist item. I need to handle the onPress so I can use react navigation 5 to send the users to a different screen.

I'm using an array of data to create a card like component that renders in the flatlist.

how do I make the individual list items touchable?

here's what I'm working with:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

import BigButton from "../components/BigButton.js";
import HomeScreenImage from "../components/HomeScreenImage.js";
import HomeCard from "../components/Card";

const homeOptions = [
  {
    name: "Beast shedule",
    body: "Create and manage your workout shedule",
    image: require("../assets/images/DoubleBis.jpg"),
    id: "1",
  },
  {
    name: "Pre-Made Workouts",
    body: "Use one of our pre-made workouts",
    image: require("../assets/images/ChickA.jpg"),
    id: "2",
  },
  {
    name: "Statistics",
    body: "Analyse your personal statistics",
    image: require("../assets/images/WorkoutInProgress.jpg"),
    id: "3",
  },
  {
    name: "History",
    body: "Keep track of your workout history",
    image: require("../assets/images/ChickH.jpg"),
    id: "4",
  },
];

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={Styles.containerTop}>
      <View>
        <HomeScreenImage style={Styles.top} />
        <View style={Styles.top}>
          <BigButton title="Train & Track" />
        </View>
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView style={Styles.flatListContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={homeOptions}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return <HomeCard info={item} />;
          }}
          keyExtractor={(homeOption) => homeOption.id}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerTop: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#3E3636",
  },
  top: {
    flex: 1,
    height: "1%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  flatListContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";

const HomeCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={Styles.container}>
      <View style={Styles.cardContainer}>
        <Image style={Styles.imageStyle} source={props.info.image} />

        <View style={Styles.infoStyle}>
          <Text style={Styles.titleStyle}>{props.info.name}</Text>
          <Text style={Styles.bodyTextStyle}>{props.info.body}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const deviceWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").width);
const offset = 25;
const radius = 20;
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: deviceWidth - 20,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  cardContainer: {
    margin: 10,
    width: deviceWidth - offset,
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: radius,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.75,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    elevation: 3,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    height: 130,
    width: deviceWidth - 25,
    borderTopLeftRadius: radius,
    borderTopRightRadius: radius,
    opacity: 0.95,
  },
  titleStyle: {
    color: "#F5EDED",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "800",
  },
  bodyTextStyle: {
    fontWeight: "200",
    color: "#F5EDED",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  infoStyle: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginVertical: 1,
  },
});

export default HomeCard;
```

Comment: Can you please add your HomeCard code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your card with some touchable component, like `TouchableOpacity` for example, with `naviagtion.navigate('routeName', {params})` function on `onPress` prop.

```
const HomeCard = (props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ReceiverRoute', {image: props.info image, name: props.info.name })}> ///etc any parameters you want
     <View style={Styles.container}>
       <View style={Styles.cardContainer}>
         <Image style={Styles.imageStyle} source={props.info.image} />

         <View style={Styles.infoStyle}>
           <Text style={Styles.titleStyle}>{props.info.name}</Text>
           <Text style={Styles.bodyTextStyle}>{props.info.body}</Text>
         </View>
       </View>
     </View>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

and then you navigate to a component that can receive some params.
For a cleaner example you can look into [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/). The main idea is just wrapping your card into some touchable with onpress navigation.  For the `navigation` prop, you can either pass it to your card from parent component, or use `useNavigation` [hook](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/)

Comment: I have that all set up thank you for the direction. I'm Still facing an issue. I need each of the rendered cards to take me to different screens depending on the card that was selected, with completely different layouts and navigators in them. I cant seem to find anything in the doc's that would enable me to do this. Any ideas mate?

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit, what the navigation will be dependent on? But the first thing i can suggest is some conditional navigating, e.g.: ```props.info.name === 'History' ? navigation.navigate('SomeHistoryScreen') : 'some other expression'```